# Panorama Video Transformation Question

Tags: 360video

I saw that Insta360 sample video linked below can be viewed as a full panorama in the google drive preview, but when I download the video and play it on VLC or any other media player, it does not look the same as in the google drive preview.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rV-X9kHn9n3ueGzHIHOSy046mEsV1cO8/edit

Is there any way I can easily transform the video files to create full panorama views as seen in the google drive video?

Thank you so much for the help!